# Python-Clicking on all hrefs on a page with selenium but with different proxies?

Tags: python, selenium

As the title states, how can i use selenium python bindings with chromedriver(specifically), to visit a page, and click on an href and be redirected, but have different proxy settings each time a visit the next href. I just need sample code. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can get all your links with beautifulsoup. Then open a new selenium webbrowser with a different proxy each time with those links

Comment: I have done that and it works, but in this case doing that is not possible. I need to be redirected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Check these 2 examples from stack over flow itself

Example 1

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.http_proxy = "ip_addr:port"
prox.socks_proxy = "ip_addr:port"
prox.ssl_proxy = "ip_addr:port"

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Example 2

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
server = Server("path/to/browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

from selenium import webdriver
profile  = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_proxy(proxy.selenium_proxy())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)


proxy.new_har("google")
driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk")
proxy.har # returns a HAR JSON blob

server.stop()
driver.quit()
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40113706/6626530

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40628176/6626530