# How to add multiple proxies in Python web automation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I want to ask that in my simple Python code how can I add multiple proxies in python web automation.

```
# importing required package of webdriver
import time
from selenium import webdriver
    
link = input("Write Your Link : ")
    
# Just Run this to execute the below script
driver = webdriver.Edge("C:\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe")

# link
    
driver.get(link)
    
while True:
     time.sleep(4)
     driver.refresh()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set proxy server with selenium and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48498349/set-proxy-server-with-selenium-and-chrome)

Comment: Bro can you please tell how to add multiple proxies

Comment: That isn't your question. You will need to edit or make a new question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple [google search](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/set-proxy-in-selenium) gave this result

```py
from selenium import webdriver
PROXY = "11.456.448.110:8080"
chrome_options = WebDriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Bro can you please tell how to add multiple proxies

Comment: What do you mean by multiple proxy? At a single time, you will use one proxy only, isn't it?

Comment: bro means that random proxy between multiple proxy list

Comment: `for proxy in proxy_list: `do your operation